# Tengo dos collections , old_user y new_user y quiero en una de ellas introducir dos campos con los valores que tienen en la otra,pero me da valor null

Tags: javascript, mongodb

He probado a pasar la collection entera ,y si me guarda el valor, como un array(lógico), pero yo lo que quiero es que solo me guarde en la collection old_user de la collection new_user los campos newField y secondField con sus respectivos valores pero me los guarda como null,  este es el código:

```
db.getCollection("old_user").find()
  .forEach((elm) => {

    let elmId = elm.id

    let new_user = db.getCollection("new_user").find( {id : elmId}).toArray()

      if(new_user) {
        db.getCollection("old_user").updateOne({id: elmId}, {$set: {newfield: new_user.newField, secondfield: new_user.secondField}})
      }
  })
```

Hasta donde yo se, para acceder a un objeto dentro de un array es con la anotación del punto, si hago una consulta de la collection entera me la devuelve pero si hago un console.log de new_user.newField me lo devuelve como null

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: Para encontrar el nuevo usuario no será mejor `findOne`? porque find devuelve un array de resultados, por lo tanto `new_user.newField` no existe

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @Pipe , efectivamente ese era el problema!!! horas y horas y no daba con la solución!! mil gracias de verdad, puedes ponerlo en respuestas para dartela como válida? Un saludo!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando `find`

```
let new_user = db.getCollection("new_user").find( {id : elmId}).toArray()
```

Y `find` retorna múltiples elementos.
Por lo tanto la propiedad `new_user.newField` no existe.

Debes cambiarlo por `findOne`:

```
let new_user = db.getCollection("new_user").findOne( {id : elmId}).toArray()
```